Vertext Edge TFLite Object Detection Bounding box is off the screen with React Native TFLite/Skia
I am using VertexAI to train for Object Detection.  I have created by data set as per documentation.  I am using 1000x1000px images for training data.  Then I export the Edge ML model as a .tflite file and import to my project.
My React Native app uses a camera from RNVision Camera.  I also installed the TF Lite package.  The app is functional so it seems like it's setup right.  However, my bounding box on the screen is not what I expect, as the Skia bounding box is out of screen view as you can see:

Here is what I am doing with the frameProcessor:
const frameProcessor = useSkiaFrameProcessor(
    frame => {
      'worklet';
      if (!modelFile?.runSync) {
        return frame;
      }

      frame.render();
      runAtTargetFps(30, () => {
        // 1. Resize 4k Frame to match model reqs vision-camera-resize-plugin
        const resized = resize(frame, {
          scale: {
            height: 512,
            width: 512,
          },
          pixelFormat: 'rgb',
          dataType: 'uint8',
        });

        const done = modelFile.runSync([resized]);
        const [boundingBoxes, labels, scores] = done;
        const top = boundingBoxes[0] as number;
        const left = boundingBoxes[0 + 1] as number;
        const bottom = boundingBoxes[0 + 2] as number;
        const right = boundingBoxes[0 + 3] as number;

        // Function to add a new position
        function addPosition() {
          const newPosition = { top, left, bottom, right };
          // If the array is already at max length, remove the oldest item
          if ((positions.value?.length || 0) >= maxLength) {
            const copy = [...(positions.value || [])];
            copy.shift();
            positions.value = copy;
          }

          // Add the new position to the end of the array
          positions.value = [...(positions.value || []), newPosition];
        }
        if (scores[0] >= 0.7) {
          addPosition();
          const position = calculateAveragePosition();
          box.value = position;
          labelText.value =
            objectDetectMap[labels[0] as keyof typeof objectDetectMap];
        } else {
          box.value = null;
        }
      });
      if (box.value) {
        const rect = Skia.XYWHRect(
 // without multiplier, box is tiny & off screen
          box.value.left * frame.width,
          box.value.top * frame.height,
          (box.value.right - box.value.left) * frame.width,
          (box.value.bottom - box.value.top) * frame.height
        );

        const rectPaint = Skia.Paint();
        rectPaint.setStyle(PaintStyle.Stroke);
        rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        rectPaint.setColor(Skia.Color('red'));
        frame.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);
        if (font) {
          const fontPaint = Skia.Paint();
          fontPaint.setColor(Skia.Color('red'));
          const text = Skia.TextBlob.MakeFromText(
            labelText.value || 'Move Closer',
            font
          );
          frame.drawTextBlob(
            text,
            box.value.left * frame.width,
            box.value.top * frame.height,
            fontPaint
          );
        }
      }
    },
    [modelFile, box, calculateAveragePosition, sharedLoadingModel]
  );

My frame is 1920x1080.  I also tried a smaller resolution below the 1024 image max that is mentioned in the Vertex documentation, however with the resize plugin to a 512x512 RGB I didn't think the frame itself matters?
What is wrong with my logic?
